# What counting principle is used in the case where 4 couples and each couple must sit together?

Tags: probability

In how many ways can 8 people be seated in a row if there are 4 married couples and each couple must sit together?

The answer is $4!2^4$. I would like to confirm if we use the basic principle of counting to get the multiplication of $2^4$? Is this a $5$-stage counting?

> **The generalized basic principle of counting**
> If $r$ experiments that are to be performed are such that the first one may result
> in any of $n_1$ possible outcomes; and if, for each of these $n_1$ possible outcomes,
> there are $n_2$ possible outcomes of the second experiment; and if, for each of the
> possible outcomes of the first two experiments, there are $n_3$ possible outcomes
> of the third experiment; and if ..., then there is a total of $n_1 · n_2 ··· n_r$ possible
> outcomes of the $r$ experiments.

Comment: Essentially yes. Not clear to me what you mean by a "5-stage" counting, esp since that term isn't used. If you referred to it as a "5 experiment" counting, then that's clearer to me.  (Note also, of course that the 1st experiment can be thought of as 4 sub-experiments ...)

Comment: There are $4!$ ways to permute the couples (treating each couple as a unit) and $2$ ways to order the individuals within each couple.

Comment: @CalvinLin You are right. "5 experiments" counting is probably a better way to phrase it. I think the first experiment is to order the four couples (A,B,C,D). The second experiment is to order the A couples; the third experiment is to order the B couples, and so on. So, it is $4!* 2*2*2*2$. However, I'm do not know what rules are used when  considering the first experiment as comprising four sub-experiments.

Comment: Personally I find it more helpful thinking of the Rule of Sum, Rule of Product, Counting the Complement, and Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion.